# Show depth data with ARKit and MetalKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, metalkit

I am total beginner in Swift & iOS, and I am trying to:

1. Visualise the depth map on the phone screen, instead of the actual video recording.
2. Save both the RGB and depth data stream.

I am currently stuck on the first one. I am using ARKit4 with MetalKit. It seems that I can get the depth data from the frame, but the visualisation that I am rendering is really bad. According to the ARKit4 video (https://youtu.be/SpZyxHkmfqE?t=1132 - with timestamp), the quality of the depth map is really low, the colors are actually different, and the distant objects are not shown at all (of course, I do not mean really distant objects, but even on ~1m it already completely fails in the indoor static environment). Examples are in the bottom of the question.

My `ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import Metal
import MetalKit
import ARKit

extension MTKView : RenderDestinationProvider {
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, MTKViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {
    
    var session: ARSession!
    var configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    var renderer: Renderer!
    var depthBuffer: CVPixelBuffer!
    var confidenceBuffer: CVPixelBuffer!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set the view's delegate
        session = ARSession()
        session.delegate = self
        
        // Set the view to use the default device
        if let view = self.view as? MTKView {
            view.device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            view.delegate = self
            
            guard view.device != nil else {
                print("Metal is not supported on this device")
                return
            }
            
            // Configure the renderer to draw to the view
            renderer = Renderer(session: session, metalDevice: view.device!, renderDestination: view)
            
            renderer.drawRectResized(size: view.bounds.size)
        }
        
        //let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleTap(gestureRecognize:)))
        //view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        // Create a session configuration
        //let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.frameSemantics = .sceneDepth

        // Run the view's session
        session.run(configuration)
        
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        
        // Pause the view's session
        session.pause()
    }
    
    /*@objc
    func handleTap(gestureRecognize: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Create anchor using the camera's current position
        if let currentFrame = session.currentFrame {
            
            // Create a transform with a translation of 0.2 meters in front of the camera
            var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
            translation.columns.3.z = -0.2
            let transform = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
            
            // Add a new anchor to the session
            let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: transform)
            session.add(anchor: anchor)
        }
    }
    */
    // MARK: - MTKViewDelegate
    
    // Called whenever view changes orientation or layout is changed
    func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {
        renderer.drawRectResized(size: size)
    }
    
    // Called whenever the view needs to render
    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        renderer.update()
    }
    
    // MARK: - ARSessionDelegate
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // Present an error message to the user
        
    }
    
    func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
        // Inform the user that the session has been interrupted, for example, by presenting an overlay
        
    }
    
    func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
        // Reset tracking and/or remove existing anchors if consistent tracking is required
        
    }
}
```

My `Renderer.swift` (only the modified functions `updateCaptureImageTextures(frame: ARFrame)` and `drawCapturedImage(renderEncoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder)`:

```
import Foundation
import Metal
import MetalKit
import ARKit

protocol RenderDestinationProvider {
    var currentRenderPassDescriptor: MTLRenderPassDescriptor? { get }
    var currentDrawable: CAMetalDrawable? { get }
    var colorPixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat { get set }
    var depthStencilPixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat { get set }
    var sampleCount: Int { get set }
}

// The max number of command buffers in flight
let kMaxBuffersInFlight: Int = 3

// The max number anchors our uniform buffer will hold
let kMaxAnchorInstanceCount: Int = 64

// The 16 byte aligned size of our uniform structures
let kAlignedSharedUniformsSize: Int = (MemoryLayout<SharedUniforms>.size & ~0xFF) + 0x100
let kAlignedInstanceUniformsSize: Int = ((MemoryLayout<InstanceUniforms>.size * kMaxAnchorInstanceCount) & ~0xFF) + 0x100

// Vertex data for an image plane
let kImagePlaneVertexData: [Float] = [
    -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
    1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0,
]


class Renderer {
    let session: ARSession
    let device: MTLDevice
    let inFlightSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: kMaxBuffersInFlight)
    var renderDestination: RenderDestinationProvider
    
    // Metal objects
    var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!
    var sharedUniformBuffer: MTLBuffer!
    var anchorUniformBuffer: MTLBuffer!
    var imagePlaneVertexBuffer: MTLBuffer!
    var capturedImagePipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState!
    var capturedImageDepthState: MTLDepthStencilState!
    var anchorPipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState!
    var anchorDepthState: MTLDepthStencilState!
    var capturedImageTextureY: CVMetalTexture?
    var capturedImageTextureCbCr: CVMetalTexture?
    
    // Captured image texture cache
    var capturedImageTextureCache: CVMetalTextureCache!
    
    // Metal vertex descriptor specifying how vertices will by laid out for input into our
    //   anchor geometry render pipeline and how we'll layout our Model IO vertices
    var geometryVertexDescriptor: MTLVertexDescriptor!
    
    // MetalKit mesh containing vertex data and index buffer for our anchor geometry
    var cubeMesh: MTKMesh!
    
    // Used to determine _uniformBufferStride each frame.
    //   This is the current frame number modulo kMaxBuffersInFlight
    var uniformBufferIndex: Int = 0
    
    // Offset within _sharedUniformBuffer to set for the current frame
    var sharedUniformBufferOffset: Int = 0
    
    // Offset within _anchorUniformBuffer to set for the current frame
    var anchorUniformBufferOffset: Int = 0
    
    // Addresses to write shared uniforms to each frame
    var sharedUniformBufferAddress: UnsafeMutableRawPointer!
    
    // Addresses to write anchor uniforms to each frame
    var anchorUniformBufferAddress: UnsafeMutableRawPointer!
    
    // The number of anchor instances to render
    var anchorInstanceCount: Int = 0
    
    // The current viewport size
    var viewportSize: CGSize = CGSize()
    
    // Flag for viewport size changes
    var viewportSizeDidChange: Bool = false
    
    var depthTexture: CVMetalTexture?
    var confidenceTexture: CVMetalTexture?
    
    .......................................

    func updateCapturedImageTextures(frame: ARFrame) {
        // Create two textures (Y and CbCr) from the provided frame's captured image
        //
        guard let depthData = frame.sceneDepth ?? frame.sceneDepth else { return }
        var pixelBufferDepth: CVPixelBuffer!
        pixelBufferDepth = depthData.depthMap
        
        var texturePixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat!
        setMTLPixelFormat(&texturePixelFormat, basedOn: pixelBufferDepth)
        depthTexture = createTexture(fromPixelBuffer: pixelBufferDepth, pixelFormat: texturePixelFormat, planeIndex: 0)
        
        pixelBufferDepth = depthData.confidenceMap
        setMTLPixelFormat(&texturePixelFormat, basedOn: pixelBufferDepth)
        confidenceTexture = createTexture(fromPixelBuffer: pixelBufferDepth, pixelFormat: texturePixelFormat, planeIndex: 0)
        
        let pixelBuffer = frame.capturedImage
        if (CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount(pixelBuffer) < 2) {
            return
        }
    
        capturedImageTextureY = createTexture(fromPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, pixelFormat:.r8Unorm, planeIndex:0)
        capturedImageTextureCbCr = createTexture(fromPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, pixelFormat:.rg8Unorm, planeIndex:1)
    }
    
    func createTexture(fromPixelBuffer pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, pixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat, planeIndex: Int) -> CVMetalTexture? {
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, planeIndex)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, planeIndex)
        
        var texture: CVMetalTexture? = nil
        let status = CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(nil, capturedImageTextureCache, pixelBuffer, nil, pixelFormat, width, height, planeIndex, &texture)
        
        if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
            texture = nil
        }
        
        return texture
    }
    
    func drawCapturedImage(renderEncoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder) {
        guard let textureY = capturedImageTextureY, let textureCbCr = capturedImageTextureCbCr, let depthTexture = depthTexture, let confidenceTexture = confidenceTexture else {
            return
        }
        
        // Push a debug group allowing us to identify render commands in the GPU Frame Capture tool
        renderEncoder.pushDebugGroup("DrawCapturedImage")
        
        // Set render command encoder state
        renderEncoder.setCullMode(.none)
        renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(capturedImagePipelineState)
        renderEncoder.setDepthStencilState(capturedImageDepthState)
        
        // Set mesh's vertex buffers
        renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(imagePlaneVertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: Int(kBufferIndexMeshPositions.rawValue))
        
        // Set any textures read/sampled from our render pipeline
        //renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(CVMetalTextureGetTexture(textureY), index: Int(kTextureIndexY.rawValue))
        //renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(CVMetalTextureGetTexture(textureCbCr), index: Int(kTextureIndexCbCr.rawValue))
        renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(CVMetalTextureGetTexture(depthTexture), index: 2)
        //renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(CVMetalTextureGetTexture(confidenceTexture), index: 3)
        
        // Draw each submesh of our mesh
        renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangleStrip, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 4)
        
        renderEncoder.popDebugGroup()
    }
}
```

Everything else is the same like in MetalKit default template of Xcode.

So, do I access the data in some wrong way? Do I have some configuration parameters wrong? Do I just render the depth map in some bad way? Or the sensor on new iPhone just really has so bad data (though does not look like, as I have managed to acquire decent 3D point clouds with some apps from AppStore, even on distance of 3-4 meters).

**Update:** I've figured out that the quality is better if I change `renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(CVMetalTextureGetTexture(depthTexture), index: 2)` to `renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(CVMetalTextureGetTexture(depthTexture), index: 1)`. This is, however, just a random observation because the documentation is... well, not very extensive. The rendered image is, however, still green-to-white, while I want it to be either grayscale, or looking as the RGB map shown in the referenced video (that would be perfect, but the grayscale version would be enough).

[image]

[image]